# Synonym for $\Delta\Sigma$

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

At the moment, we have tag [delta-sigma](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-sigma). Some use $\Delta\Sigma$, others use $\Sigma\Delta$. I am more familiar with the latter, for example. Hence, I propose that the synonym [sigma-delta](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sigma-delta) be created.

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for your various edits and suggestions. I think you have some good ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done!

[image: Done!]